# Cannot limit number of checkboxes selected (tried multiple snippets)

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, checkbox

I have a form that prints out a list of questions stored in the database. The user is supposed to select a maximum of 10 check boxes, but it seems my javascript is being ignored. Am I blanking out on something fundamental to get this to work? I am creating this in a virtual machine with LAMP. I've tried running the code inside Eclipse and in the browser, but nothing happens. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Question Selection</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function chkcontrol(j) {
                var total = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < document.questions.questions.length; i++) {
                    if (docment.questions.questions[i].checked) {
                        total = total + 1;
                    }
                    if (total > 10) {
                        alert("Please select only 10 questions");
                        document.questions.questions[i].checked = false;
                        return false;
                    }
                }   
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo "<br />"; ?>
        <form id="questions" name="questions" action="GenerateQuiz" method="post">
            <table border="2" style="margin:0 auto; padding:5px">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Questions</th>
                        <th>Include in Quiz</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php 
                        $count = 1;
                        // Print a row for each record in the returned query
                        foreach($questionList as $key => $row) {
                            echo "
                                 <tr>
                                    <td style='text-align:left;'>$row[questionText]</td>
                                    <td style='text-align:center;'><input type='checkbox' name='questions[]' onclick='chkcontrol($count)' value='$row[questionText]' /></td>
                                 </tr>";
                            $count++;
                        }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div align="center">
                <br />
                <input type="submit" value="Take Quiz" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I realized in my code, "document" was mispelled. I corrected that, but it doesn't make the code work.

Comment: Check you have a misspelled here if `(docment.questions.questions[i].checked) {...` you are missing an "o" in document

Comment: Caught that I think just as you were typing your comment. No luck though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chkcontrol = function(j) {
    var total = 0;
    var questions = document.getElementsByName('questions[]');
    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
        if (questions[i].checked) {
            total = total + 1;
        }
        if (total > 10) {
            alert("Please select only 10 questions");
            questions[i].checked = false;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Is what your chkcontrol function should look like.  You do not need jQuery to do this, you were most of the way there!

See a working example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/wr58739c/4/

Comment: Thank you, this code works perfectly. I searched a few sites to learn how to do it, but the syntax just didn't look right.

Answer (score 1):

Ive tried this in jquery which will be much easier. I have statically created some questions and you might loop your questions from your database. Here I have restricted user to select only 2 questions **$('.quesCheck:checked').length > 2** . You can change it to 10

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.quesCheck',function()
    {
       if($('.quesCheck:checked').length > 2)
       {
            alert("Please select only 2 question");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr><td>What is thunder ?</td><td><input type="checkbox" name='questions[]' class="quesCheck" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>What is lightning?</td><td><input type="checkbox" name='questions[]' class="quesCheck" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>What is chain reaction?</td><td><input type="checkbox" name='questions[]' class="quesCheck" /></td></tr>
     </table>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with your script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function chkcontrol(j) {
            var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('#questions input[type="checkbox"][name="questions[]"]');
            var total = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
                if (document.checkboxes[i].checked) {
                    total = total + 1;
                }
                if (total > 10) {
                    alert("Please select only 10 questions");
                    document.checkboxes[i].checked = false;
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

With that code you ensure you get the right checkboxes from the right form.